# tex Error: While including includegraphics

Tags: latex, tex

I am getting the following error while compiling my .tex document:

```
! Argument of \@tempa has an extra }.<inserted text>\par \maketitle
```

I am using texstudio on macos and using miktex.

```
\documentclass
[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\graphicspath{Figures/} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter 
    \title  {\vspace{+1cm}{\includegraphics[width=30mm]{logo.pdf}}\\
        \vspace{+1cm}
        test}
    \authors  {\texorpdfstring
        {\href{ibrar.ahmad@gmail.com}{Ibrar Ahmed}}
        {Ibrar Ahmed}
    }
    \addresses  {\group\\\deptname\\\univname}  
    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a link to which of the trillions of thesis classes you are using?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz What do you mean of that, I have created a small tex file to reproduce the problem.

Comment: We cannot reproduce it without the `Thesis` class mentioned in your documentclass.

Comment: @IbrarAhmed We need  your thesis class to reproduce the problem. This class is not included in the major tex distributions and searching for it on the internet won't help because there are so many different classes with the same name. If we were to try your code we would get the error `File Thesis.cls not found. \graphicspath`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, please take a look at https://pastebin.pl/view/d2883bfb

Comment: @IbrarAhmed Thanks! If I combine this with https://www.yatex.org/gitbucket/HiroseLabo./2019-kameya/blob/master/lstpatch.sty your code works fine for me. Try to remove all the auxiliary and compile again. Is your tex distribution up to date? Can you show the .log file from compiling the example from your question?

Comment: off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}`, your class already loads it

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, here is the log https://pastebin.pl/view/46c2a2dd

Comment: You have some very old .sty files in the folder of your document, e.g. for graphicx - they probably interfere with your tex distribution, which otherwise looks fairly up to date

Comment: Yahoo, after upgrading graphics.sty it works. Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz